# Deploying Sharepoint Add-ins updates not updating

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio

I have developed a SharePoint hosted Add-in and deployed it on our internally hosted SharePoint 2016 environment. This works fine, but if I update the project (for example make a list field required) and update the deployed app it does not include the change. However, if you delete the app and the add the updated version the changes are present - but doing it this way deletes any data that has been entered. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I got around the problem by putting the lists in the parent site and referencing them from there.